# Error when reading in float in Fortran

Tags: fortran

This should be quite simple, but I can't manage to read in a floating point number in Fortran. My program test.f looks like this:

```
  PROGRAM TEST
  open(UNIT=1,FILE='test.inp')
  read(1,'(f3.0)')line

  STOP
  END
```

The input file `test.inp` simply contains a single float: `1.2`

Now the compiling of my testfile goes fine, but when I run it I get an error:

> At line 4 of file test.f (unit = 1, file = 'test.inp')
>
> Fortran runtime error: Expected REAL for item 1 in formatted transfer, got INTEGER
>
> (f3.0)
>
> ^

I've tried different modifications of the code and also googling for the error message, but with no result. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Frank

Comment: Whilst this doesn't answer the question, you should really declare the type of all variables you use. In your code nowhere do you state the type of `line`. It is good practice to include the line `implicit none` at the top of a program, function, subroutine or module (before any `use` statements). Implicit type declarations, which is what you have used, can cause lots of nasty, hard to find bugs.

Comment: This actually does answer the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable `line` is implicitly defined as integer. This doesn't work with the`f` edit descriptor. If you want to read an integer use `i` edit descriptor (`i3` for example). Otherwise declare `line` as real to math the "f" descriptor.

Note beside: the .0 is not a problem, because if Fortran gets a number with decimal point the .0 part in the descriptor is ignored. It is only used when an number without a decimal is entered and then it uses the number behind the decimal point in the desciptor to add a decimal point into the right place. For with `F8.5`, `123456789` is read as `123.45678`. More ont this here http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/fortran/lin/compiler_f/lref_for/source_files/pghredf.htm .

Comment: Things like `123456789` being read as `123.45678` are precisely why I personally try to avoid specifying formats as long as I possibly can.

Answer (score 1):

In your read statement

```
read(1,'(f3.0)')line
```

the `f3.0` tells tour program to read 3 digits with 0 digits after the decimal (this is what the n.m syntax means). So I presume that the program is just reading `1` from the file (not `1.2`), which is an integer. Try replacing that line with something like

```
read(1,'(f3.1)')line
```

although, if the number in your file is likely to change and be larger than 9.9 or have more than one decimal place you should increase the field width to something larger than 3.

See the documentation of the [`read` intrinsic](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlf101a.doc%2Fxlflr%2Fread.htm) and for [data edit descriptors](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlf101a.doc%2Fxlflr%2Fread.htm) for more information on reading and writing in Fortran.

**Edit**: the format specifier, the second argument in quotes in your read statment, has the form `fw.d`, where `f` indicates that the data to read is a floating point number, `w` is the width of the field including all blanks and decimal points and `d` specifies the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: It does not cause a runtime error to get a number with no decimal point on input when reading real. With this `read(1,'(f3.1)')` line Fortran would read `11` as `1.1`.

Comment: The "w" part of a "f" descriptor is overridden on input if the item has a decimal point.   This is not the problem here.

Comment: @VladimirF Good point. Format descriptors and something I try and stay away from, but the `.0` in the question code stood out to me as a possible reason for the error, However, looking into it further your answer is clearly the explanation here.
@M.S.B. Assuming line is a `real`, the format descriptors `'(f1.1)'`, `'(f2.1)'` and `'(f3.1)'` read 0.1, 1.0 and 1.2 respectively, so the 'w' part is not ignored - or am I missing something here?

Comment: A mistake: I meant to write that the "d" part of "w.d" is ignored on input, if the input characters include a decimal point.   So this part of the "F" format specification rarely matters on input since people virtually always include the decimal point in floating point numbers.  Back in the days of card decks people would save key strokes by omitting the decimal point and relying on the format specifier to position the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading/writing list formatted data, unless you have a very strong reason to do otherwise. assuming that you're reading in from a file with just a single float or integer in a single line, like this

```
123.45
11
42
```

then this should do the reading

```
real*8 :: x,y,z
open(1,file=filename)
read(1,*)x
read(1,*)y
read(1,*)z
close(1)
```

Comment: Presumably you mean list-directed formatting rather than unformatted, as unformatted means, colloquially, binary data.